# Open Graph data does not display on Discord

Tags: html, metadata, meta-tags

I was browsing my websites and i have noticed that the Open Graph data on one of my sites was no longer displaying on **discord**. I have tried to change

```
<meta property="og:url"                content="url" />
<meta property="og:type"               content="website" />
<meta property="og:title"              content="site name" />
<meta property="og:description"        content="description" />
<meta property="og:image"              content="image url" />
```

Firstly i tought it was related to some settings that might have changed on my part, on discord, but after checking everything, seems that was not the case.

[image: issue]

As can be seen in the above screenshot, (1) and (2) my links, both used to have the OG data working, and (3) is Youtube that displays properly.

I have tried to play around with the OG data, i was thinking that might be an issue due to the text/title/image lenght/size, but also that was not the case.

*In order to check if the OG Data was properly set and working i have also tried the links on "https://www.opengraph.xyz/" and also on Whatsapp / Facebook where the data is being displayed, so the issue is on* ***discord*** *only*.

If anyone has an ideea what is the issue with **discord**, help would be greatly apreciated.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Note: the `<meta>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: Thank you for the note Rob, but this does not help the issue i have posted above. The closing slash does not affect the tag.

Comment: Which is exactly why I never understand why anyone puts a closing slash there. It does nothing, has no meaning, is uncalled for in the specification and browsers are instructed to ignore it. So it is pointless, worthless and only takes up space.

Comment: @Rob It is required when building your website with XHTML5. Or just want your HTML to be complete.

Comment: @Ben221199 The question is tagged HTML. Putting a slash in there does not make it complete because no specification states it is required or needed, it doesn't do anything, and browsers are instructed to ignore it. You can't even find any examples of it anywhere in the specifications for any tag/element.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert, but here's how I got it working.

As far as I know, the 3 most basic opengraph meta's are `og:title`, `og:description` and `og:image`.

For most websites, a relative path to your `og:image` should work, but there are exceptions like on Discord.

Try changing your `og:image` from something like:
`"images/opengraph.png"` to `"https://yourwebsite.com/images/opengraph.png"`.

The opengraph image may be cached on Discord for a long time, so if you'd like to refresh it to see changes there, you could change the image filename. Additionally, you could add a query parameter to the end of your URL, which will force Discord to refresh the image for that URL if its previous path isn't available anymore. Example: `"https://yourwebsite.com?"`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing the `og:site_name` meta tag

This is what my solution ended up looking like inside of Django templates, so that's where the jinja2 looking syntax is coming from.

```
<meta name="og:site_name" content="Pawn Guild"></meta>
<meta property="og:title" content="{{ pawn.name }}">
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Level {{ pawn.level }} {{ pawn.vocation }}"></meta>
<!-- <meta name="theme-color" content="#91ee91"> -->

{% if pawn.picture %}
    <meta property="og:image" content="{{ pawn.picture.url }}" >
{% endif %}
```

The `{{ pawn.picture.url }}` is a relative path from my domain... So for example, your url should look something like `/path/to/img`, not `www.mydomain.com/path/to/img`.

The `theme-color` meta tag changed the sidebar color in the card. I found mine looked pretty good without it, so I left it in there commented.

Here's the result: [image: Discord card Example]

These 2 links were helpful for me figuring this out:

- https://cookieandrock.dev/posts/candr-website-005
- https://www.reddit.com/r/discordapp/comments/82p8i6/a_basic_tutorial_on_how_to_get_the_most_out_of/

Answer (score 0):

### **For anyone still running into this problem:**

Many websites (including Discord) will not show Open Graph data from an unsecure http website. IT MUST BE HTTPS!

I copied my headers into an empty url page and hosted it on https://tiiny.host, and my title/images showed perfectly on Discord.